# How do I create a Setup program for a Windows Service without using InstallShield?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, service, deployment

I'm looking for a way to create and/or add a Setup program for this Windows Service I'm developing. The requirements are that there can be no 3rd-party material (InstallShield, InstallUtil.exe, WiX, etc.); it must be done strictly from C#, and I have to pass an argument to the service prior to installation of the service.

I'm basically just writing a service that monitors a user-specified folder, and its subdirectories, for a specific change. I have the service and its installer built already, but I need to be able to distribute the service to clients' machines, and the only thing my service needs from them is that folder path during installation.

I've searched all over SO and the Goog, but I've found very little to help me build my own setup, so if anyone can please help me with a tutorial on here, or a link to a currently-existing full tutorial on how to build your own setup program without any 3rd-party stuff, that would be fantastic.

Here's my generic code split into their respective files:

Program.cs:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
namespace MyService
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            ServiceBase.Run( new MyService( args ) );
        }
    }
}
```

MyService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
namespace MyService
{
    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        public MyService( string[] args )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ServiceName = "MyService";
            this.AutoLog = this.CanHandlePowerEvent = 
            this.CanHandleSessionChangedEvent = this.CanPauseAndContinue = false;
            this.CanStop = this.CanShutdown = true;
        }
        protected override void OnStart( string[] args )
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(/*'watcher' arguments*/)
            { IncludeSubdirectories = true /*, Set NotifyFilters*/};
            watcher.Changed += ( sender, e ) => { /*Handle the event*/; };
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            base.OnStart( args );
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            watcher.Dispose();
            base.OnStop();
        }
        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            watcher.Dispose();
            base.OnShutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

ProjectInstaller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
namespace MyService
{
    [RunInstaller( true )]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EventLogInstaller eventLogInstaller =
                this.Installers.Cast<Installer>().First
                    ( installer => installer is EventLogInstaller ) as EventLogInstaller;
            if( eventLogInstaller != null )
                eventLogInstaller.Log = "MyService";
            this.Installers.Add( new ServiceProcessInstaller() 
            { Username = null, Password = null } );
            this.Installers.Add( new ServiceInstaller() 
            { StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic } );
        }

        protected override void OnAfterInstall( IDictionary savedState )
        {
            base.OnAfterInstall( savedState );
            using( ServiceController controller = new ServiceController
                ( this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName, Environment.MachineName ) )
            { controller.Start(); }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the clients to be able to just double-click on the setup file, and that brings up a single window that asks them for the top directory path to which they want the service to watch. Obviously, I will need to build a GUI for that with directory browser functionality, which I can do easily enough, but I don't know how to pull it all together. So, can someone please tell me how to add these three files, or the executable from building them?, to a setup program so I can get the path, pass it to the service (which I will do from the command line, but I already know how to do that part, too), and get it up and running on my clients' machines?

Comment: Why not use a technology like Wix or InstallShield?  This is why they exist, to help package things up and give you a professional looking installer.

Comment: @JohnKoerner There are a few reasons why I don't want to use anything like that. 1: I want to know how it works behind the scenes. Maybe one day I'll create one of my own or include similar functionality. 2: I don't need anything powerful like that; I'm just creating a rinkydink little service for a very particular thing. 3: That's more technology I'd have to rely on that a) may have security holes and b) may go obsolete eventually. It makes more sense to understand how to do it myself than to rely on someone else to do it. So why not learn about it now?

Comment: Wix is [open source](https://github.com/wixtoolset) (MS-RL), so you could use that code to learn how installers work.  Wix builds up an MSI and there are base actions in the MSI to do things like installing services and registering your product in Add/Remove programs. Another advantage is that you can bootstrap your installer to ensure that the correct version of .net is installed before you start the install. If you roll your own, you need to handle all this yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKoerner. I'll look through that and see if it can help me. In the meantime, if you come across anything like what I described in my post, please post back here.

Answer (score 1):

I have built few windows services that we ship to the end user's . The following is the architecture

1. I build the windows services
2. I created a few `.bat` files that will do the tasks

> 1. Install a service using ServiceController sc.exe
> 2. Start / Stop / Uninstall using the same service controller

The user has to just decompress the deliverable and right click on the bat and say "Run As Administrator".

You can chain-up several lines like install, start and in a single bat file.

To find / learn more about sc.exe, please refer [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251192)
Sample :
`sc create newservice binpath= c:\nt\system32\newserv.exe type= own start= auto depend= "+tdi netbios"`

Comment: thank you for your response, but it doesn't address my need as outline in the body of my post. I'm looking for "a tutorial on here, or a link to a currently-existing full tutorial on how to build your own setup program without any 3rd-party stuff." It must be done strictly with C# and be a single file (Setup program), which means no BAT, XML, etc. I want to make it as simple as it can be for my clients: They simply double click the installer (Setup), and they're done. I can create the meat of the installer, but I need a template for it from which to launch.

Comment: @Meloviz Hey, send your App and OP will certainly integrate the code for you. (facepalm) He told you what you need. The command line installs the service. Just `Process.Start` it. Check the exit code. Really easy! And add a custom command line to your tool "--install" and just run the install command line process and notify user of success or failure. Make sure you are in Administrator mode (elevated).